# matplotlib stacked bar plots bugged after version update

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

Using the following code:

```
 for index,axis in enumerate(axes):
            for counter, bar in enumerate(axis):
                max_height = start_extra_heights[counter]
                w, h = bar.get_width(), bar.get_height()
                if 0.0 < h < need_arrow:
                    plt.annotate(value_format.format(h)+'%', xy=(bar.get_x(), bar.get_y()),
                                 xytext=(bar.get_x() + 0.2, max_height + jumps[counter]), color=suit_colors_dict[index],
                                 arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
                    jumps[counter] += proportion_to_high * 1.2
                elif h > 0.0:
                    plt.text(bar.get_x() + w / 2, bar.get_y() + h / 2, value_format.format(h)+'%', ha="center",
                             va="center")
        # adding the number of total lines of the original pileups
        for index, bar in enumerate(axes[-1]):
            max_height = start_extra_heights[index]
            if max_height == 0.0:
                max_height = 1.3
            plt.annotate(value_format.format(sum_column[index]), xy=(bar.get_x(), bar.get_y()+bar.get_height()),
                         xytext=(bar.get_x(), max_height + jumps[index]),
                         arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='fancy'))

    return plt, axes
```

I was able to generate plots like this one:
[image]

On a different python environment(conda), I was executing the command (from a different user that was executing the script for the graphs)

`pip install matplotlib –user`

Since then, the plots are not always created (the tiff file in not created or created but empty) and if they do, the colors are merged (see for example orange and pink colors for "rep" column) and the text overlaps each other (like in "norep" column, brown and purple):
[image]

I tried to uninstall the matplotlib package from the same user and reinstall a different version I believe was there before but the buggy graphs persists.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Which versions are being used in each case?

Comment: @MattThompson The version that was installed after I executed `pip install ...` was 3.3.3 but I am not sure what was the version before that - I suspect versions 3.1.0 or 3.1.1.
We tried to reinstall to these versions on the user that executes these graph scripts but we get the same results.